# hard NLP task and help me to use less saxon variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

with your help, i could submit assignment of my XSLT NLP project. Now it stays a  subsidiary question and i need your help but i step up from from the first i posted here. It's again a grammatical dependency question. Here is the xml file, pretty big. It's just a sample :

```
<items>
<item type="forme" pos="2422"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>SUB(2424)</a><a>SUB(2424)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>_</a><a>-</a><a>88.94980459452675</a><a>87.88045697486253</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>174.99999999999716</a><a>179.99999999999972</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>B</a><a>B_mlm1</a><a>mlm1</a><a>U</a><a>U_mmm3</a><a>motherless_mmm3</a><a>motherless</a><a>mmm3</a><a>U</a><a>U_mmm3</a><a>U_weak_mmm3</a><a>weak</a><a>mmm3</a><a>U</a><a>U_weak</a><a>U_weak_mmm3</a><a>weak</a><a>mmm3</a><a>45.5326</a><a>45.7076</a><a>(IU:B)_(PER:B)_(PAQ:U)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:B)</a><a>(PRN:B)_(PER:B)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:U)_(PER:B)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2423"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2424"><f>suis</f><c>V</c><l>être</l><a>B</a><a>indicative</a><a>present</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>W</a><a>W</a><a>-</a><a>88.77778177606523</a><a>88.84206635041087</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>210.00000000000085</a><a>151.6666666666661</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>B</a><a>B_mmh2</a><a>filled-dis_mmh2</a><a>filled-dis</a><a>mmh2</a><a>B</a><a>B_mmh2</a><a>B_filled-dis_mmh2</a><a>filled-dis</a><a>mmh2</a><a>B</a><a>B_filled-dis</a><a>B_filled-dis_mmh2</a><a>filled-dis</a><a>mmh2</a><a>45.7076</a><a>45.9576</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:I)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2425"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2426"><f>arrivée</f><c>V</c><l>arriver</l><a>B</a><a>past_participle</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>fem</a><a>PRED(2424)</a><a>PRED(2424)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>88.45345484675228</a><a>89.06843157657143</a><a>U</a><a>U_mmh1</a><a>mmh1</a><a>350.0000000000014</a><a>148.03333333333293</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>filled-dis</a><a>mmh2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>filled-dis</a><a>mmh2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>filled-dis</a><a>mmh2</a><a>45.9576</a><a>46.5476</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:I)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2427"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2428"><f>euh</f><c>I</c><l>euh</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>U</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>89.23188854563097</a><a>86.90747618692372</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>ml</a><a>164.0999999999977</a><a>240.000000000002</a><a>$L2</a><a>0.564099999999996</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>filled-pause_ml</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>ml</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>U_filled-pause_ml</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>ml</a><a>U</a><a>U_filled-pause</a><a>U_filled-pause_ml</a><a>filled-pause</a><a>ml</a><a>46.5476</a><a>46.7117</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:U)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:U)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:I)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:U)_(PER:I)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2429"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2430"><f>au</f><c>Pre+D</c><l>à+le</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>OBL(2426)</a><a>OBL(2426)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>_</a><a>-</a><a>91.17726670940492</a><a>89.25355862295885</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>105.00000000000398</a><a>254.999999999999</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>B</a><a>B_hh</a><a>lone_hh</a><a>lone</a><a>hh</a><a>B</a><a>B_hh</a><a>B_strong_hh</a><a>strong</a><a>hh</a><a>U</a><a>U_weak</a><a>U_weak_mm</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>47.2758</a><a>47.3808</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:I)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2431"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2432"><f>Kenya</f><c>N</c><l>Kenya</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>DEP(2430)</a><a>DEP(2430)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>L</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>W</a><a>-</a><a>90.63523576955845</a><a>92.34505203351132</a><a>U</a><a>U_mh</a><a>mh</a><a>309.99999999999517</a><a>136.25000000000222</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>hh</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hh</a><a>U</a><a>U_strong</a><a>U_strong_mh</a><a>strong</a><a>mh</a><a>47.3808</a><a>47.8908</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:L)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2433"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2434"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>SUB(2436)</a><a>SUB(2436)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>W</a><a>W</a><a>-</a><a>91.04741819099613</a><a>92.09349964868443</a><a>U</a><a>U_hh</a><a>hh</a><a>140.00000000000057</a><a>179.99999999999972</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>B</a><a>B_mm</a><a>included_mm</a><a>included</a><a>mm</a><a>U</a><a>U_hh</a><a>U_weak_hh</a><a>weak</a><a>hh</a><a>U</a><a>U_weak</a><a>U_weak_hh</a><a>weak</a><a>hh</a><a>47.8908</a><a>48.0308</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2435"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2436"><f>voulais</f><c>V</c><l>vouloir</l><a>B</a><a>indicative</a><a>imperfect</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>W</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>90.8710165296283</a><a>90.65073592388268</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>109.99999999999943</a><a>122.5000000000005</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>mm</a><a>U</a><a>U_hm</a><a>U_weak_hm</a><a>weak</a><a>hm</a><a>U</a><a>U_weak</a><a>U_weak_hm</a><a>weak</a><a>hm</a><a>48.0308</a><a>48.2408</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2437"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2438"><f>travailler</f><c>V</c><l>travailler</l><a>B</a><a>infinitive</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>OBJ(2436)</a><a>OBJ(2436)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>W</a><a>-</a><a>89.41299029419082</a><a>89.56178263216408</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>119.99999999999744</a><a>145.00000000000136</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>mm</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>U_strong_mm</a><a>strong</a><a>mm</a><a>U</a><a>U_strong</a><a>U_strong_mm</a><a>strong</a><a>mm</a><a>48.2408</a><a>48.6108</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2439"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2440"><f>d</f><c>Adv</c><l>d'abord</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>W</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>88.54065975723061</a><a>88.38652395835068</a><a>B</a><a>B_mml2</a><a>mml2</a><a>230.00000000000398</a><a>104.99999999999865</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>B</a><a>B_mH</a><a>included_mH</a><a>included</a><a>mH</a><a>B</a><a>B_mm</a><a>B_weak_mm</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>B</a><a>B_weak</a><a>B_weak_mm</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>48.6108</a><a>48.9408</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2441"><f>'</f><c>-</c><l>-</l><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>W</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>88.54065975723061</a><a>88.38652395835068</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mml2</a><a>230.00000000000398</a><a>104.99999999999865</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>mH</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>48.6108</a><a>48.9408</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2442"><f>abord</f><c>-</c><l>-</l><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>L</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>W</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>88.54065975723061</a><a>88.38652395835068</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>mml2</a><a>230.00000000000398</a><a>104.99999999999865</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>mH</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>48.6108</a><a>48.9408</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2443"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2444"><f>pour</f><c>Pre</c><l>pour</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>OBL(2438)</a><a>OBL(2438)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>88.1931350919146</a><a>87.81429338479211</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>99.99999999999432</a><a>137.50000000000284</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>mH</a><a>B</a><a>B_mH</a><a>B_strong_mH</a><a>strong</a><a>mH</a><a>B</a><a>B_weak</a><a>B_weak_ml</a><a>weak</a><a>ml</a><a>48.9408</a><a>49.0408</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2445"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2446"><f>le</f><c>D</c><l>le</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>DEP(2448)</a><a>DEP(2448)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>87.85945849774988</a><a>87.7272888420905</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>ml</a><a>100.00000000000142</a><a>160.00000000000014</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>mH</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mH</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>weak</a><a>ml</a><a>49.0408</a><a>49.1408</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2447"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="2448"><f>gouvernement</f><c>N</c><l>gouvernement</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>sg</a><a>masc</a><a>DEP(2444)</a><a>DEP(2444)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>L</a><a>L</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>89.30093037414093</a><a>91.7898816990675</a><a>U</a><a>U_mh</a><a>mh</a><a>250.0</a><a>149.99999999999858</a><a>$L2</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>mlm1</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>included</a><a>mH</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>mH</a><a>U</a><a>U_strong</a><a>U_strong_mh</a><a>strong</a><a>mh</a><a>49.1408</a><a>49.7808</a><a>(IU:L)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2449"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2450"><f>£</f><c>DELIM</c><l>£</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2451"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2452"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="2453"><f>§</f><c>DELIM</c><l>§</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
```

In fact i need to extract the SUB item (a[7] = SUB(\d+)). I need to grab this word and the word at index of SUB(number) which it's the pos attribute of the governor. In the following example, item with @pos = 2434 has a[7] = SUB(2436). I need to get this word. The form of words is f. One item = one word.
The RETURN statement is the end of a sentence. So in my example, i need to extract item with f = "je" and verb governor at @pos 2436 = f = "suis". When the dependent (the subject) is before the verb, i have no problem. But sometimes, the governor is before the subject and with my method, i have no clue to get it. Furthermore, as you have to print the other text, you have to pay attention to many things : add upper case at the fist word of sentence, add a final point...
Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" extension-element-prefixes="saxon" exclude-result-prefixes="saxon">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="count" saxon:assignable="yes" select="1"/>
    
    <xsl:template match ="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <html>
            <body>
                <span style="text-align: center; color : #ff4d4d; font-size: x-large;  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;"><h2><i>Mise en relief de la relation SUB</i></h2></span>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//item" group-ending-with="item[f/text() = 'RETURN']">
            <xsl:variable name="governor" as="item()*">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[contains(a[7], 'SUB')][@type='forme']"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <saxon:assign name="count" select="1"/>
            <xsl:variable name="dep" select="$governor[2]"/>
            <p>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:if test="current()[@type='forme'][f/text() != 'RETURN' and f/text() != '&amp;']">
                <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$governor[$count] lt $governor[$count+1]">
                        <span style="border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000; padding: 1px;background-color : #ffe6e6; color : #cc0000; font-weight: bold;"><xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(f/text(),1,1)),
                            substring(f/text(), 2), ' '[not(last() )], ' ')"/></span>
                        <saxon:assign name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$count mod 2 = 0 and $governor[$count]=@pos">
                            <span style="border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000; padding: 1px;background-color : #e6e6ff; color : #cc0000; font-weight: bold;"><xsl:value-of select="concat(f/text(), ' ')"/></span>
                            <saxon:assign name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$count mod 2 != 0 and $governor[$count]=@pos">
                            <span style="border:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#FF0000; padding: 1px;background-color : #ffe6e6; color : #cc0000; font-weight: bold;"><xsl:value-of select="concat(f/text(), ' ')"/></span>
                            <saxon:assign name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=1 and $governor[$count] != @pos">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(f/text(),1,1)),substring(f/text(), 2), ' '[not(last())],' ')"/>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                   </xsl:choose> 
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:if test="position() = last()"></xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="'.'"/>
            </p>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="item[@type='forme']">
        <xsl:for-each select="current()">
            <xsl:variable name="gov">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="item[contains(a[7], 'SUB')]">
        <xsl:sequence>
        <xsl:value-of select="@pos"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(a[7], 'SUB\((\d+)\)', '$1')"/>
        </xsl:sequence>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know i'm using saxon variable and it' cheat. I would like to get a method or to have an idea to get the governor when it's before the subjet. And if you have some advices, it's gonna with pleasure that i'll take them. Help me too to get this code easier to read. I need to use modulo operator do distinguish governor (printed with a color) and dependant (printed with another one) to make contrast between them.
The simplified output is like that :

```
<p><b>Je</b> <i>suis<i> arrivé au Kenya euh <b>je</b> <i>voulais</i> travailler..."until RETURN statement in f node of one item"</p>
```

My code can do that because the verb governor is after the subjet (SUB) but i can't get my verb ans my subj when subj is after the governor. Here i have no example but imagine a sub with an index of governor lesser than his @pos (before him in the sentence).
To sum up, i need to print all text in html format and make more visible subjects and governors that go together. My code works when the subj is before the governor. Example : "Hello !" says Mary. For this example, it doesn't work.

EDIT

Okay right, my question is maybe too specific. I would like to get back the item SUB and the item with the governor verb to create a list a nodes on which i could iterate and have access to childs of item nodes. I try some things but without success.

```
    <xsl:template match="//item">
        
        <xsl:variable name="nodes" as="node()*" select="//item"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="current()[@type='forme'][contains(a[7], 'SUB')]">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(@pos) lt number(replace(a[7], 'SUB\((\d+)\)', '$1'))">
                 <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                 <xsl:copy-of select="$nodes[replace(a[7], 'SUB\((\d+)\)', '$1')]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                 <xsl:copy-of select="$nodes[replace(a[7], 'SUB\((\d+)\)', '$1')]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
 
    </xsl:template>
```

What should i do to have a list of nodes from this template ? It should encapsulate the two nodes together but i have no idea about structures to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make much sense to me. Some issues:

In a `match` pattern using `match="item"` is sufficient, there is no difference and no advantage to use `match="//item"`.

`current()` gives you a single node so I don't understand why you want to process it with an `xsl:for-each`.

If the condition `[@type='forme'][contains(a[7], 'SUB')]` matters, why don't you put it in either the `match="item[@type='forme'][contains(a[7], 'SUB')]"` or further up where you apply templates to item elements?

Comment: i keep your advises chief. Do you know why in my html output i have many empty <p></p> ?
For brevity, it's a french guy guy coding in assembly for many years that need to give a piece of work in XSLT. the mix is not good.